# WiX: Copy a file from local folder to installation folder

Tags: wix, cmd, action, file-copying

I'm using a WiX setup project to build an MSI package.

I want the MSI, to do a copy of the given file during the installation to the installation folder from the one, where the .msi file is running from.

I read on WiX a bit, and what I found is the `<CopyFile... />` element supposed to do that.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I've figured out what the issue is.
The problem is that the SourceDirectory of the CopyFile element supposed to point to the Directory tag id.
Instead, I've used SourceProperty attribute of the CopyFlie tag, and also defined a Property separately, which made the use of the CopyFile element correct.
So it worked.